# OpenID Is Different on This Site

Tags: support, user-accounts

Is it just me, or is it impossible to edit an openid or add an "alt. OpenID" on the new site? Any way to change it so we become more like stackoverflow, which already has both features?

**Update:** I realized that the problem was that I'm trying to add an OpenID that already exists as part of another account on the site. Had to do with my migration issues. Any way I can combine the two accounts? Trying to add the other OpenID to this account doesn't work [even though on StackOverflow I have both OpenID's associated with the same account]

Accounts: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/128/yydl and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/427/joseph

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely can.  Stack Overflow and all sites in the Stack Exchange network run on the same codebase.

Note that you cannot do this here on the child meta because your account is inherited from the parent site.  However, you can go to [your profile](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/128/yydl) on the main site and you should see an "add openid" link next to the "edit" link.

---

Since this ended up being a case of the user having two accounts, the accounts were merged. (:

Comment: Updated my question to reflect the true problem. Any way you can help?

Comment: @yydl I can merge them for you.  Can you update your post with a link to each profile please?

Comment: Added the Links... Thanks!

Comment: @yydl, merged! (: